# MySQL join two tables with datetime interval

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm working on a type of bot detection system that helps me run some ML to identify this traffic.

Long story short, I have two tables:

1. One table contains all of the server log data (requests down to the second level) with a datetime column
2. One table that has a row for an exceptional event I have identified. (with a datetime column)

What I need to do is be able to join table 2 with 1 and get a list of server requests 1 and 5 minutes before each exceptional event.

So I have two tables and want to do a join between them and sum up the server request column. The join criteria should be that table A's time is within 1 and 5 mins of table B's time.

So B.time <= A.time <= B.time + (1|5) minutes

Here is the code and I have indexes (btree) on both datetime columns. But it appears to run SUPER SLOW. Anything I can do differently?

The log table has a few million rows and the exceptions table about 3,000.

```
SELECT
    a.Name AS ExceptionName,
    SUM(b.Requests) AS Requests1MBefore,
    SUM(c.Requests) AS Requests5MBefore,
FROM exceptions a
LEFT JOIN log b
ON
    b.Datet <= a.Datet
    and a.Datet <= DATE_ADD(b.Datet, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
LEFT JOIN log c
ON
    c.Datet <= a.Datet
    and a.Datet <= DATE_ADD(c.Datet, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
GROUP BY
    a.name
```

I expect the output to be a joined table that looks like this:

```
Exception Name | Requests1MBefore | Requests5MBefore
Event1         | 50               | 500
Event2         | 10               | 1000
....
```

Comment: Do just a single JOIN for 5 min and use conditional aggregation for 1 min column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
SELECT e.Name AS ExceptionName,
       SUM( l.Datet > DATE_SUB(e.Datet, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) as Requests1MinBefore,
       COUNT(l.Datet) as Requests5MinBefore
FROM exceptions e LEFT JOIN
     log l
     ON l.Datet <= e.Datet AND
        l.Datet > DATE_SUB(e.Datet, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
GROUP BY e.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not SARGable. Using a function on column in join or in where conditions forces a table scan.
I would suggest that you should create 2 generated/computed columns in the table *log*. One column will store the time 1 minute before the actual time and the other column will store the time 5 minutes before.

After this you can use these 2 new columns to join the table. You can also index this 2 new columns to make search even faster.

Though, this approach will increase the cost of insertion in table *log*. So you need to carefully consider this approach.

Let me know if this helps.